# MDX query producing #Error as output

Tags: ssas, mdx, moving-average

In my SSAS Cube, I have a measure called [Sales Total]. What I want to do is to create another measure that would give me the lowest sales figure in the last 6 months. I want this to be a **moving minimum**, calculated as the min of sales of every time period from the present month to 6 months back.

I wrote my MDX statement but it produces an error and I have hard time trying to figure out why. It is something to do with aggregating Date dimension members into a filter aggregate.

When i choose a single month member from the Date hierarchy, it returns the correct value. When I select multiple members from the hierarchy, as seen below, it errors out.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[Min Sales Total Rolling 6 months] as '(MIN([Date].[Fiscal Month Hierarchy].currentmember.lag(6):[Date].[Fiscal Month Hierarchy].currentmember,[Measures].[Sales Total]))'
MEMBER [Date].[Fiscal Month Hierarchy].[FilterAggregate] as 
'AGGREGATE({
[Date].[Fiscal Month Hierarchy].[Quarter].&[20141].&[201310],
[Date].[Fiscal Month Hierarchy].[Quarter].&[20141].&[201311],
[Date].[Fiscal Month Hierarchy].[Quarter].&[20141].&[201312],
[Date].[Fiscal Month Hierarchy].[Quarter].&[20142].&[201401],
[Date].[Fiscal Month Hierarchy].[Quarter].&[20142].&[201402],
[Date].[Fiscal Month Hierarchy].[Quarter].&[20142].&[201403],
[Date].[Fiscal Month Hierarchy].[Quarter].&[20143].&[201404],
[Date].[Fiscal Month Hierarchy].[Quarter].&[20143].&[201405],
[Date].[Fiscal Month Hierarchy].[Quarter].&[20143].&[201406],
[Date].[Fiscal Month Hierarchy].[Quarter].&[20144].&[201407]
})'
SELECT {
[Measures].[Min Sales Total Rolling 6 months]} ON AXIS(0)
FROM [My Cube]
WHERE ([Date].[Fiscal Month Hierarchy].[FilterAggregate])
```

Comment: I understood the [Measures].[Min Sales Total Rolling 6 months] but I did not the [Date].[Fiscal Month Hierarchy].[FilterAggregate], what are you trying to do with this date member?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in [this blog by one of the SSAS developers](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/mosha/archive/2005/11/18/writing-multiselect-friendly-mdx-calculations.aspx) already many years ago, multi select does not work with `CurrentMember`. You should use

```
MEMBER [Measures].[Min Sales Total Rolling 6 months] as 
MIN(Tail(EXISTING [Date].[Fiscal Month Hierarchy].[Fiscal Month Hierarchy].Members).Item(0).Item(0).lag(6)
    :
    Tail(EXISTING [Date].[Fiscal Month Hierarchy].[Fiscal Month Hierarchy].Members).Item(0).Item(0),
    [Measures].[Sales Total])
```

instead.

`EXISTING` gets the set of all selected members. This is needed as there is no single `CurrentMember`. Then `Tail` gets the set consisting of the last of these members, `Item(0).Item(0)` converts that single element set to a member.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that multi-select does not work with CurrentMember and the proposed solution. 
It works only when I remove the EXISTING keyword from the second parameter of the RANGE function. Otherwise I get an error, why is that?

The Range function expects a member expression for the 2 argument. A tuple set expression was used.

Comment: @Thracian Sorry, the `EXISTING`s should have been inside the `Tail`. I corrected my code.

Comment: Thanks, the solution works perfect! I wish I were able to give you more than +1